# How to overwrite list?

Tags: c#, list

I need collection that is similar to list, instead of always adding items when particular length is reached it should start overwriting values from the first index and continue in circular order.

I.e. for 4 items limit:

```
specialList.Add(100); // {100}
specialList.Add(101); // {100, 101}
specialList.Add(102); // {100, 101, 102}
specialList.Add(103); // {100, 101, 102, 103}
specialList.Add(104); // {104, 101, 102, 103}
specialList.Add(105); // {104, 105, 102, 103}
```

Comment: How are you going to know what values to overwrite? You can refer to items by index (`myList[index] = newValue`) and set the new value

Comment: do you wants to keep for example always last 10 items? or clearing the list is ok?

Comment: @S.Serp yes,i need to keep last 10 items. It turns out that the length of the list will be limited to 10 items and new items will overwrite the old starting from the beginning.

Comment: You cannot achieve that with standard list implementation. The best way to implement something like that is create custom list which inherits from IList<> interface.

Comment: @PawelMaga a simple implementation is shown on my answer

Comment: If you really need such type - ignore answers here and search for "circular buffer" which is what the question asks for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the `list`, why not just clear your `list` and then start adding items.

Clear your `list` by using the following method:

```
myList.Clear();
```

and then add items in your `list`:

```
myList.add(item);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the old values, then once the `list` is filled with 10 items, add a new item at first index as shown below:

```
myList[0] = (newItem);
```

`newItem` will overwrite the first item in your `list`

Comment: maybe he wants to keep old values for example always last 10 items

Comment: @Yousaf thank you for your answer,but i need to keep old values in list.

Comment: @Yousaf, Thank you very much, everything was easier than i thought.

Answer (score 7):

(Updated to show a General list class)
This is a class which could be used for special list class that loops (cycles to the first item) when reached to last element:

```
public class ListCycle<T> : IList<T>
{

    int curIndex = -1;
    List<T> list;
    int nMax;

    public ListCycle(int n)
    {
        list = new List<T>(n);
        nMax = n;
    }

    /// <summary>returns the current index we are in the list</summary>
    public int CurIndex { get { return curIndex; } }

    public int IndexOf(T item) { return list.IndexOf(item); }
    public bool Contains(T item) { return list.Contains(item); }
    public int Count { get { return list.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return list.GetEnumerator(); }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return list.GetEnumerator(); }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index]; }
        set { list[index] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        curIndex++; if (curIndex >= nMax) curIndex = 0;
        if (curIndex < list.Count)
            list[curIndex] = item;
        else
            list.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        list.Clear();
        curIndex = -1;
    }

    //other mehods/properties for IList ...
    public void Insert(int index, T item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public bool Remove(T item) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void RemoveAt(int index) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

}
```

Usage is easy as:

```
var list = new ListCycle<int>(10);

//fill the list
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}

//now list is:
// 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

//add more items will start from first
list.Add(100); //overrides first item
list.Add(101); //overrides second item

//now list is:
// 100, 101, 2, 3, ...
```

Comment: @S.Serp Thank you for great answer! I think a lot of people will find it useful. But i liked the simple solution, which Yousaf gave.

Comment: i updated my answer to define a general special list class, which could be more useful. i think the answer like `myList[0] = (newItem);` as provided by other user is so obvious and not so simple to use in practice.. that way you have to track the curIndex yourself